# EPPlus create same tables in different worksheet

Tags: c#, epplus

I am trying to create the same tables in two different worksheet but it doesn't seem to work.

I create my tables using this code :

```
public void createWS(ExcelPackage package)
{
   ExcelWorksheet ws = package.Workbook.Worksheets["WorkSheet1"];
   createTables(ws);
   ws = package.Workbook.Worksheets["WorkSheet2"];
   createTables(ws);
}

public void createTables(ExcelWorksheet ws)
{
   ws.Tables.Add(ws.Cells[1, 1, 301, 1], "Level 1");
}
```

When I try to create the second one I get the error :

> TableName is not unique

Do you have any idea how to create the same table in two different worksheet ?

Comment: How about combine worksheet name and table name? Btw, you can copy rows with data, styles, etc. It will look like copy of table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Excel proper (nothing to do with code or EPPlus) requires table names be unique in the same `workBOOK`.  You can try this manually in Excel to see this.  So you will have to adjust your function and pass in the table name as a parameter:

```
public void createTables(ExcelWorksheet ws, string TableName)
{
   ws.Cells[1, 1].Value = "Col1"; //EPPlus generated file will not open properly with this if the cells are all empty
   ws.Tables.Add(ws.Cells[1, 1, 301, 1], TableName);
}
```

And provide different names.

Comment: But now, "Excel has met an unreadable content" when I add a table inthe same place but with a different name x)

Comment: Its probably an issue with the column names not being defined - a quark with EPPlus.  Try defining cell 1,1 before adding the table.  So put something like `ws.Cells[1, 1].Value = "Col1";` (see my edit above).  It has to do with the sharedstring.xml files not containing the default column names added by EPPlus

Comment: OKay, I figured out what it was. I was doing that for my first table : `worksheet.Tables.Add(worksheet.Cells[2, 13 + value, 302, 13 + value], "Niveau " + value);`    and this for my second : `worksheet.Tables.Add(worksheet.Cells[2, 13 + value, 302, 13 + value], value.toString());`   and apparently EEplus didn't like the second case, and I had to had a string like in the first one to make it work....